# trying to determine whether the first and last letters of a string are the same

Tags: python, string

first and last () is used to call a function that determines whether the first and last letters of a string are the same

```
def first_and_last(message):
    if message[0] == message[-1]:
        return True
    elif message[0] != message[-1]:
        return False
    elif message == "":
        return False



print(first_and_last("else"))
print(first_and_last("tree"))
print(first_and_last(""))
```

```
C:\Users\angel\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:\Users\angel\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\app.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\angel\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\app.py", line 13, in <module>
    print(first_and_last(""))
  File "C:\Users\angel\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\app.py", line 2, in first_and_last
    if message[0] == message[-1]:
IndexError: string index out of range
True
False

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: If the string is empty there is no first and last ;)

Comment: You need to have special handling for the case where the string is empty or None.

Comment: Start by testing if the string empty with: if message == "" and then the logics, that cover this specific case.

Comment: You should check if `message == ""` first.

Comment: The full body of the function boils down to `return message != '' and message[0] == message[-1]`.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with the empty string input `""`, as python cannot find a 0th or -1st index of this, it throws an error before reaching the `elif` statement. If you check for an empty string first, then you will avoid this error:

```
def first_and_last(message):
    if message == "":
        return False
    elif message[0] == message[-1]:
        return True
    elif message[0] != message[-1]:
        return False
```

Output:

```
True
False
False
```

**Edit:** there are many comments on the question and this answer on shorter ways to achieve this goal, which are all valuable. This answer is just explaining why OP gets the error and how to fix it using only their code

Comment: Would make sense to also improve the code to simply do `return message[0] == message[-1]` after the first `if`

Comment: @luk2302 The answer has a good explantion concerning the error. But one could add the other approach to the answer.

Comment: I don't want to steal other's answers, but can edit the question to add if people don't post their own :)